# Call ahk script from url (github gist)

Tags: github, autohotkey

Is there a way to call/load an ahk script from https. Like [this one](https://gist.github.com/gimoya/5821469/raw/034b2766bbcbe70e2a8e93b72d1ec8723351a8f8/Veg%C3%96K-Abk%C3%BCrzungen). I'd like to keep this file for public editing on github and it would be called from multiple users without the need to download it first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about downloading it:

```
UrlDownloadToFile, https://gist.github.com/gimoya/5821469/raw/034b2766bbcbe70e2a8e93b72d1ec8723351a8f8/Veg%C3%96K-Abk%C3%BCrzungen, hotstrings.ahk
if(ErrorLevel || !FileExist("hotstrings.ahk") ) {
    msgbox, Download failed!
    ExitApp
}
Run, hotstrings.ahk
```

You may want to add some check routines for the downloaded file to make sure, that it's syntactically correct and most of all not harmful. That is, you can't trust anything coming from the internet. A more secure way to apporach this would be to retrieve your hotstrings as XML or JSON and build them dynamically on your own; blindly executing downloaded code is very risky, especially when multiple users are able to edit it arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks, this would work - only new lines are missing in the downloaded ahk file..

Comment: @Kay If you are talking about caching, try passing the request a fake get parameter to make it unique.

Comment: No, I was intending to say that the line breaks in the downloaded ahk file are missing. I'm new to AHK - for caching I wouldn't know how to make up a fake get parameter..

Comment: @Kay What AHK version are you using? The output is correct when I run it.

Comment: 6.1 BTW, I put your code lines to an ahk file to run it, is this the proper way?

Comment: Sorry - this was most likely only an issue with the text editor - in Notepad++ everything looks fine and the script is working! Thanks!

Comment: @Kay Good to hear. I still urge you to implement some kind of safety. Anyone who can edit the hotstring file will be able to inject all kinds of malicious payload. Every client will then execute it automatically.