# How to download a dropbox file?

Tags: autohotkey

Here is some code I got from one of the other responses:

```
UrlDownloadToFile, https://gist.github.com/gimoya/5821469/raw/034b2766bbcbe70e2a8e93b72d1ec8723351a8f8/Veg%C3%96K-Abk%C3%BCrzungen, hotstrings.ahk
if(ErrorLevel || !FileExist("hotstrings.ahk") ) {
    msgbox, Download failed!
    ExitApp
}
Run, hotstrings.ahk
```

I tried to modify it to my needs by changing the URL but it just shows this sign:
Download failed and that the compressed zip folder is invalid.

Comment: Here is OP's source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363085/call-ahk-script-from-url-github-gist

Comment: Could you possibly provide a sample dropbox link that we can use to debug and find a solution for your problem?

Comment: here is the link:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o325f21gzo8qn6n/Trial.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you just get the direct download link for the Dropbox file, it works just fine:

```
URLDownloadToFile, % "https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1emirfeqbnu8tu/hello.txt?dl=1", % "my_cool_file.txt"
```

<sup>(Thanks to the first link on Google for this random example Dropbox file)</sup>

Adding `?dl=1` gives the direct link.

Comment: I need it to be a zip file which I have on my personal dropbox. Please help me with that.

Comment: Works exactly the same (assuming the link isn't private somehow, at least the example link in your comment isn't and it works just fine with the code in this answer). Is there something specific you're having trouble with? Just change the url and the filename in my answer.

Comment: I think that there is simething wrong with my desktop. I cant make any new folders there and it is not letting me downloads things there. Do you know how I can change is so it downloads in the 'Downloads folder?

Comment: I already tried

URLDownloadToFile, % "https://www.dropbox.com/s/o325f21gzo8qn6n/Trial.zip?dl=0", Downloads"delete.exe.ahk"

but that didn't work.